# Kafka Consumer not getting invoked when the kafka Producer is set to Sync

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a requirement where there are 2 topics to be maintained 1 with synchronous approach and other with an asynchronous way.
The asynchronous works as expected invoking the consumer record, however in the synchronous approach the consumer code is not getting invoked.

Below is the code declared in the config file

```
 props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9093");
 props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 3);
 props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
 props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
 props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
 props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
```

I have enabled autoFlush true here

```
 @Bean( name="KafkaPayloadSyncTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaPayload> KafkaPayloadSyncTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String,KafkaPayload>(producerFactory(),true);
 }
```

The control stops thereafter not making any calls to the consumer after returning the recordMetadataResults object

```
  private List<RecordMetadata> sendPayloadToKafkaTopicInSync() throws   InterruptedException, ExecutionException {      
        final List<RecordMetadata> recordMetadataResults = new ArrayList<RecordMetadata>();
        KafkaPayload kafkaPayload = constructKafkaPayload();
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String,KafkaPayload>> 
future = KafkaPayloadSyncTemplate.send(TestTopic, kafkaPayload);
        SendResult<String, KafkaPayload> results;
        results = future.get();
        recordMetadataResults.add(results.getRecordMetadata());     
        return recordMetadataResults;           
    }
```

Consumer Code

```
public class KafkaTestListener {    
    @Autowired
    TestServiceImpl TestServiceImpl;    
    public final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1); 
    @KafkaListener(id="POC", topics = "TestTopic", group = "TestGroup")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String,KafkaPayload> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        countDownLatch.countDown();     
        TestServiceImpl.consumeKafkaMessage(record);        
        System.out.println("Acknowledgment : " + acknowledgment);
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();       
    }
}
```

Based on the issue, I have 2 questions

1. Should we manually call the listen() inside the Listener Class when its a Sync Producer. If Yes, How to do that ?
2. If the listener(`@KafkaListener`) get called automatically, what other setup/configurations do I need to add to make this working.

Thanks for the inputs in advance

-Srikant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be sure that you use `consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");` for Consumer Properties.

Not sure what you mean about sync/async, but produce and consume are fully distinguished operations. And you can't affect consumer from your producer side. Because in between there is Kafka Broker.

Comment: This property is already added in the consumerprops. In my case, the messages are not getting consumed.

Do you mean, the consumer operation should work irrespective of whether I have declared my producer type to work either in sync mode or in async mode ?

Comment: Sync Mode : I expect an ack, hence I have declared the KafkaTemplate with autoFlush set as true.
Async Mode : I invoke the callback method of future.

Comment: Of course it doesn't matter if there is consumers on the topic on the other side. Producer just sends messages to topic. Sync/async in this case means how you wait for the confirmation that message is stored in the topic. Here is absolutely nothing about consumer(s). Not sure what's going on. Maybe you could share some simple Spring Boot application on the matter and we will look at it for flaws.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong initially, but its working now, might be some other dependency issue.
Thanks for the response its working now.